# Using Metric Aggregation with Composite Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have the following mapping for an index:

```
{
  "test5" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic" : "false",
      "properties" : {
        "messageType" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "groupId" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "payload" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "include_in_root" : true,
          "properties" : {
            "request" : {
              "type" : "nested",
              "include_in_root" : true,
              "properties" : {
                "data" : {
                  "type" : "nested",
                  "include_in_root" : true,
                  "properties" : {
                    "chargingPeriods" : {
                      "type" : "nested",
                      "include_in_root" : true,
                      "properties" : {
                        "endDateTime" : {
                          "type" : "date"
                        },
                        "power" : {
                          "type" : "double"
                        },
                        "startDateTime" : {
                          "type" : "date"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

First use case, I want buckets in 2 min intervals based on `payload.request.data.chargingPeriods.startDateTime` and `groupId`  with a filter criteria of `messageType` . BTW chargingPeriods is an array.

This query works for that use case:

```
GET test5/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          { "sessionId": { "terms": { "field": "groupId"} } },
          {
            "date" : {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "payload.request.data.chargingPeriods.startDateTime",
                "fixed_interval": "2m",
                "format": "MM/dd/yyyy - hh:mm:ss",
                "order": "asc"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }    
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "messageType": [
        "test"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want metric aggregations done on these composite buckets returned and I tried this:

```
GET test5/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          { "sessionId": { "terms": { "field": "groupId"} } },
          {
            "date" : {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "payload.request.data.chargingPeriods.startDateTime",
                "fixed_interval": "2m",
                "format": "MM/dd/yyyy - hh:mm:ss",
                "order": "asc"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "metricAgg": {
          "max": {
            "field": "payload.request.data.chargingPeriods.power"
          }
        }
      }      
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "messageType": [
        "test"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

According to ES documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html, this should work by doing metric aggregation on the composite bucket
But instead of the metric aggregation being computed on the composite bucket, it is being computed across all the power fields in chargingPeriods array in the entire given document.

How I created the index:

```
PUT /test5
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings" : {
      "dynamic" : "false",
      "properties" : {
        "groupId" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "messageType" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "payload" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "include_in_root": true,
          "properties": {
            "request": {
              "type":"nested",
              "include_in_root":true,
              "properties": {
                "data": {
                  "type":"nested",
                  "include_in_root": true,
                  "properties": {
                    "chargingPeriods": {
                      "type": "nested",
                      "include_in_root": true,
                      "properties" : {
                        "endDateTime":{
                          "type": "date"
                        },
                        "power": {
                          "type": "double"
                        },
                        "startDateTime":{
                          "type": "date"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Test Data:

```
    POST test5/_doc/testdocu1
{
  "groupId": "563",
  "messageType": "test",
  "payload": {
    "request": {
      "data": {
        "chargingPeriods": [
          {
            "endDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:42:25Z",
            "power": 9.62857,
            "startDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:41:55Z"
          },
          {
            "endDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:42:55Z",
            "power": 9.6491,
            "startDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:42:25Z"
          },
          {
            "endDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:43:25Z",
            "power": 9.6491,
            "startDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:42:55Z"
          },
          {
            "endDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:43:55Z",
            "power": 9.66963,
            "startDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:43:25Z"
          },
          {
            "endDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:44:25Z",
            "power": 9.67128,
            "startDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:43:55Z"
          },
          {
            "endDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:44:55Z",
            "power": 9.65079,
            "startDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:44:25Z"
          },
          {
            "endDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:45:25Z",
            "power": 9.66492,
            "startDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:44:55Z"
          },
          {
            "endDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:45:55Z",
            "power": 9.68544,
            "startDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:45:25Z"
          },
          {
            "endDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:46:25Z",
            "power": 9.68544,
            "startDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:45:55Z"
          },
          {
            "endDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:46:55Z",
            "power": 9.67434,
            "startDateTime": "2022-10-13T17:46:25Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My output:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_buckets" : {
      "after_key" : {
        "sessionId" : "563",
        "date" : "10/13/2022 - 05:46:00"
      },
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : {
            "sessionId" : "563",
            "date" : "10/13/2022 - 05:40:00"
          },
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "metricAgg" : {
            "value" : 9.68544
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "sessionId" : "563",
            "date" : "10/13/2022 - 05:42:00"
          },
          "doc_count" : 4,
          "metricAgg" : {
            "value" : 9.68544
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "sessionId" : "563",
            "date" : "10/13/2022 - 05:44:00"
          },
          "doc_count" : 4,
          "metricAgg" : {
            "value" : 9.68544
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "sessionId" : "563",
            "date" : "10/13/2022 - 05:46:00"
          },
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "metricAgg" : {
            "value" : 9.68544
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

As you can see, it chose the max payload.request.data.chargingPeriods.power from all the elements, ignoring the composite buckets. For example

```
{
  "key" : {
    "sessionId" : "563",
    "date" : "10/13/2022 - 05:40:00"
  },
  "doc_count" : 1,
  "metricAgg" : {
    "value" : 9.68544
  }
},
```

metricAgg should have been 9.62857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work the way you expect because you're aggregating nested data which you have `include_in_root`, and hence, all the nested data finds itself in the root document as if it was not nested, and so, the relation between the `startDateTime` and the `power` is basically lost.

The other issue is that your composite aggregation aggregates nested (`payload...`) and non-nested data (`groupId`), that won't work.

However, if you add the `groupId` field inside each element of your array, then you can make your query work like this:

```
GET test5/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "payload": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "payload"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "request": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "payload.request"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "data": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "payload.request.data"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "charging": {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "payload.request.data.chargingPeriods"
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "my_buckets": {
                      "composite": {
                        "sources": [
                          {
                            "sessionId": {
                              "terms": {
                                "field": "payload.request.data.chargingPeriods.groupId"
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "date": {
                              "date_histogram": {
                                "field": "payload.request.data.chargingPeriods.startDateTime",
                                "fixed_interval": "2m",
                                "format": "MM/dd/yyyy - hh:mm:ss",
                                "order": "asc"
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      "aggregations": {
                        "metricAgg": {
                          "max": {
                            "field": "payload.request.data.chargingPeriods.power"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "messageType": [
        "test"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
            {
              "key" : {
                "sessionId" : "563",
                "date" : "10/13/2022 - 05:40:00"
              },
              "doc_count" : 1,
              "metricAgg" : {
                "value" : 9.62857
              }
            },
```